# Socket and Core information - How do I check empty sockets?

Tags: linux, x86, cpu-architecture

I am trying to grab the number of sockets and core information. Till now I found that one socket can have multiple cores.

- http://rcritical.blogspot.com/2010/09/finding-cpu-socket-and-core-using.html
- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/difference-between-cpu-core-and-sockets-797991/

**But my system shows:**

```
root:~ #  dmidecode | grep "Central Processor" | wc -l
64
root:~ # grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l
16
```

Here, number of sockets is more than number of cores? How do I check empty sockets?

Answer (score 2):

In `dmidecode`'s output, you need to look for `Status: Populated, Enabled` in the socket information. So

```
dmidecode | grep -c "Status: Populated, Enabled"
```

should give you the correct result.

You'll find the same information in a more compact form with `lscpu`; this will give you (amongst other things) the number of on-line sockets, the number of cores per socket and the number of threads per core.

Comment: I got socket 2 from lscpu.